# Insert Datetime to Cassandra (by DataStax PHP Driver)

Tags: php, cassandra, datastax

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE agency (
  documentCode ASCII,
  sectionCode ASCII,
  checkedAt TIMESTAMP,

  PRIMARY KEY (franchisedCode, agencyCode)
)
;
```

I can change the structure of my database, if needed.

I would set a timestamp:

```
$cassandra = $cluster->connect($keyspace);
$statement = $cassandra->prepare('
  INSERT INTO agency 
  ( documentCode
  , sectionCode
  , checkedAt
  ) VALUES 
  ( :documentCode
  , :sectionCode
  , :checkedAt
  );
');

$arguments = [
    'documentCode'   => $code1,
    'sectionCode'    => $code2,
    'checkedAt'      => $mixed,
];

var_dump($arguments);

$options = new ExecutionOptions([
    'arguments' => $arguments,
]);

$cassandra->execute($statement, $options);
```

I tested some values for `$mixed`:

- `null` works
- `123456789` fails, even if I cast to `int` or `string`
- `'2016-06-06T12:34:56+00:00'` fails
- `'2016-06-06T12:34:56'` fails
- `'2016-06-06'` fails

The error message is `Fatal error: Uncaught Cassandra\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: Invalid value type`

Can you see something wrong? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I solved my issue. 
I have to use Object Type: 
`$checkedAt = new \Cassandra\Timestamp($checkedAt);`